# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:exec (default-cli) .This is the error when I run the java class file

Tags: maven-plugin

My pom.xml code is as under

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ktpl</groupId>
    <artifactId>Kanekar</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Kanekar-1</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jakartaee>10.0.0</jakartaee>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakartaee}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>SQL</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>12.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>12.4.0.jre8-preview</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
       <plugins>
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>config/sun_checks.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: What error exactly do you have? Can you provide output of your command?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.